# can't set border linewidth for bars of rowstacked histogram

Tags: plot, gnuplot, histogram, bar-chart

I'm plotting a histogram using gnuplot. And would like to set width of all bar borders.

I set style of my histogram bars using:

`set style fill solid border -1`

after it I would like to set linewidth for `border`, but `set style fill solid border -1` has no `linewidth` option.

Do you know any solution for this problem? Maybe there is another way to set border width for histogram bars?

Answer (score 4):

I would not use `set style fill solid border -1` (or better, `noborder`), but rather define a specific line type that can be used to customize `boxes`, e.g.

```
bw=0.1
n=500
bin(x,width) = width*floor(x/width) + bw/2.0
set boxwidth bw
set style line 2 lc rgb 'gray30' lt 1 lw 2
set style fill pattern 5 
plot 'rnd.dat' using (bin($1,bw)):(1./(bw*n)) smooth frequency with boxes ls 2
```

Here, boxes are drawn using dark gray and line width of 2.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Far from an elegant solution, but you can decrease the relative size of the border linewidth by making everything bigger (and vice versa), e.g. to halve the border linewidth, double the plot dimensions, the font sizes and all other linewidths.

Answer (score 0):

The width can be set without making a style first. The linewidth can be set directly using:

```
    plot 'data' u 1:2 w boxes lw 3
```